# Curl error: Could not resolve host: www.google.com; Name or service not known POST PHP

Tags: php, curl, post, recaptcha

im triying to do a cURL request to the recaptcha google api (https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify) and i get this:

> resource(25) of type (curl)
>   Curl error: Could not resolve host: www.google.com; Name or service not known

this is my php code:

```
        $secret_key = 'SECRET';

    // Instanciar CI
    $c = get_instance();

    // Instanciar CURL para luego hacer la solicitud HTTP POST
    $ch = curl_init();

    var_dump($ch);
    curl_setopt_array($ch, [
        CURLOPT_URL => "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify",
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
        CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => [
            'secret' => $secret_key,
            'response' => $res,
            'remoteip' => $c->input->ip_address()
        ],
    ]);

    // Hacemos la solicitud y cerramos la instancia
    //$out = curl_exec($ch);

    if(curl_exec($ch) === false)
    {
        echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Operation completed without any errors';
    }

    //var_dump($out);
    curl_close($ch);
```

what could it be?, thank you!

Comment: There's a problem with the DNS configuration on your server.

Comment: I suspect you are blacklisted from google, for toomuch request/spam.

Comment: I do the request via GET and it works... but the google guide suggest to do it via POST